# php/regex: allow dashes in this pattern

Tags: php, regex

How can I allow dashes in this pattern?

```
$str = preg_replace ( "/[^a-z \d]/i", "", $str ) ;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put it first.

```
$str = preg_replace ( "/[^-a-z \d]/i", "", $str ) ;
```